# how do I use wwScriptCompressionModule? for gzip compression with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, compression, gzip, westwind

Ok, I downloaded the WestWind Ajax Controls, and I added this to my web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="wwScriptCompressionModule" type="Westwind.Web.Controls.wwScriptCompressionModule,Westwind.AjaxToolKit"/>
</httpModules>
```

I am registering my js like this in my masterpage .cs file:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(name_of_masterpage), "scripts", ResolveUrl("~/js/all_script.js"));
```

Now from what I understand, it should be working but it is not?  I am likely missing something that is glaringly obvious, but I can't seem to find a simple tutorial or explanation anywhere.  I am only using IIS 6.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work as i think

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "scripts", ResolveUrl("~/js/all_script.js"));
```

or another method

```
HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script"); 
Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript"); 
Include.Attributes.Add("src", sInclude); 
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
```

hope this helps